# How to fix this VHDL error

Tags: fpga, vhdl, clock, process

I am getting an error in my VHDL code. It says "[Synth 8-27] else clause after check for clock not supported". Why is this?

Below is the code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
use work.Data_Sizes_Package.ALL;

entity Encoder_Counter is
  Port (Count_Input_A, Count_Input_B : in std_logic; 
        Reset_Counter : in std_logic;
        Counter_Value : out std_logic_vector(Data_width-1 downto 0)
       );
end Encoder_Counter;

 architecture Behavioral of Encoder_Counter is

signal Counter_Value_Temp : std_logic_vector(Data_width-1 downto 0) := (others => '0');

begin

Counter_Value <= Counter_Value_Temp;

    Process (Count_Input_A, Count_Input_B, Reset_Counter)
    
    begin
    
      if(rising_edge(Reset_Counter)) then
      Counter_Value_Temp <= (others => '0'); 
            
      elsif(rising_edge(Count_Input_A)) then
      Counter_Value_Temp <= Counter_Value_Temp + 1;
                  
      elsif(rising_edge(Count_Input_B)) then
      Counter_Value_Temp <= Counter_Value_Temp + 1;      

      end if;

    end Process;


end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Where's the clock in your design !!????? You are designing a sequential circuit, you need a clock for that and all other inputs should be sampled on the rising edge of the clock.

Comment: Get the fundamentals right: Add Clock, Reset in all sequential circuits.

Comment: This question is a [duplicate](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/204978/pulse-on-edge-of-different-clock).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Your synthesis tool does not support multiple-clock registers.
- Your code describes multiple clock registers.

That can't work.

Comment: Ok, this is essentially poorly written VHDL? Can this logic behaviour be achieved? Also this is intended to not be a clocked design.

Comment: @David777 depends on the device you're targetting. But you would need either a time-reference (which, in a few comments, will become "yeah, you'll need a clock for that") or you need to use your input signals as clocks, because rising edge detection *is* a clock, even if it's a very irregular one.

Comment: Since it's a counter it OUGHT to be a clocked design. You need to think more deeply about what hardware you are trying to create.

Comment: I am trying to design a counter that counts pulses from a rotary encoder, inputs A and B. It is maybe best if I feed in a much faster clock than what the input pulses are and then decide when to count up on the clock rising edge depending on the pulse logic levels?

Comment: @David777 Yes, that is the correct way to solve your issue. Make sure to synchronize your inputs to your clock domain as well.

Comment: @DonFusili Could you explain what you mean by synchronise inputs to clock domain?

Comment: @David777 In short: When taking a clock domain crossing between two non-synchronous clock domains, you can encounter metastability issues. These can be almost completely resolved by adding 2 FFs to the input signal that are clocked on the receiving clock before you read from the signal. There's more detailed explanations, but that's what Google/Educations are for.

Comment: @DonFusili Ah yeah, I am familiar with this. I'll have a go at it, thanks.